# Having trouble with Javascript basic excecution

Tags: javascript

HELP!! I am new to Java and have been stranded on this problem for the past hour and a half

> Use String class methods to manipulate these
>   strings as follows.

Use the tab escape character to line-up the outputs after the labels as
follows

```
a) proper label . . .: Output value
b) proper label . . .: Output value
c) proper label . . .: Output value
d) proper label . . .: Output value
```

1. Determine the length of string_1.
2. Determine the length of string_2.
3. Concatenate both strings.
4. Check if the two strings have same set of characters with regard to case (i.e., equal).
5. Convert string_1 to upper case.
6. Convert string_2 to lower case.
7. Extract a valid sub-string of multiple characters from string_1.

Comment: Check this out and fix your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You must additionally practice how to ask questions and use Stack Overflow, but without spoonfeeding you. You can find everything you need here:

You can calculate the length of a string using:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length

You can concatenate using the `+` symbol between two strings.

You can check if two strings are the "same set of characters" aka are exactly identical by comparing them together, (hint: `=` and an *if statement*, but do you want to use only one `=` ?). If they are equivalent, `return` what?

JavaScript has built in string manipulation methods as well that you could investigate:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase

You can also investigate a string prototype known as `substring`:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring